# Having count of open patches , but has to rename the branch

Tags: gerrit

I have to rename my branch , but having lots of open patches in that branch. How to move those open patches to new branch without cherrypick.

Cherrypick is one of the option , but has to cherry pick every patch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html) to automate this task. You can find the open changes using the [Query Changes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes) endpoint (or just the "Search" field in the Gerrit UI) and than change their destination branch using the [Move Change](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#move-change) endpoint.

For example, you could put all open changes in a file (one change number in each line) and execute the following command:

```
for c in $(cat CHANGE-FILE)
do    
    curl -s --request POST --user USER:PASSWORD --data @- --header Content-Type:application/json GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE/move << EOF
    {
        "destination_branch" : "NEW-BRANCH"
    }
EOF
done
```

Comment: Hi Marcelo
Thanks for your response. Its like moving one change at a time, but I need to move all the open changes to a new branch by a command. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you need to execute one command per change but you can automate this execution. I updated the change with more info.